# Linearize if else constraint in a MILP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization

How can you write the following if/else condition in a linear form?

If *S* ≥ 3, then *X* ≤ 1,

else *X* = 0

with
S ∈{0, 1, 2, 3}

X ∈{0, 1}

I've seen some examples where *X* is forced to a value in the if condition, but I haven't found an example where *X* **may** (i.e. ≤) have a value.

Comment: $3x \leq s$ . Assuming $x$ is already declared as binary and $s$ as integer in $[0,3]$.

Comment: I feel quite ashamed that I didn't came up with that myself. Thank you!

Comment: [Related](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76549/53274)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enforce $S \le 2 \implies X = 0$, equivalently, its contrapositive $X = 1 \implies S \ge 3$.  The standard big-M formulation is
$$3 - S \le M (1 - X).$$
Because $S \ge 0$, you can take $M = 3 - 0 = 3$:
$$3 - S \le 3 (1 - X),$$
which simplifies to $3X \le S$, as suggested by @MichalAdamaszek in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!